# jQuery if/else if statement doesn't work after the first "if"

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jQuery if/else if condition but only the "if" part works, the "else if"  do not, I can't figure out why. The code represents three listboxes (**ajax-populated**) and when any of them clicked, a jQuery function collects the ID of the clicked item and assigns it to a variable. The first one (even when I switch places I get the correct ID number) is fine, never the second or the third. It is not working when I use three "if's" instead of "if/else if" structure either.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn_edit_details').click(function() {
        var request_id;
        if ($('#lstbx_new_repeat_requests').val().length > 0) {
            request_id = $('#lstbx_new_repeat_requests').val();
            alert(request_id);
        }
        else if ($('#lstbx_approved_repeat_requests').val().length > 0) {
            request_id = $('#lstbx_approved_repeat_requests').val();
            alert(request_id);
        }
        else if ($('#lstbx_declined_repeat_requests').val().length > 0) {
            request_id = $('#lstbx_declined_repeat_requests').val();
            alert(request_id);
        }
if ($('#btn_edit_details').val() == 'edit') {
// rest of the code, working fine when the request_id is passed from the first "if"
```

And the HTML

```
<input type='button' id='btn_edit_details' value='edit' />
<select id='lstbx_new_repeat_requests' name='lstbx_new_repeat_requests'></select>
<select id='lstbx_approved_repeat_requests' name='lstbx_approved_repeat_requests'></select>
<select id='lstbx_declined_repeat_requests' name='lstbx_declined_repeat_requests'></select>
```

Comment: If the first `if` statement is always true.. it will never go to the `else if` statements

Comment: it is not always true - the val() of the listbox is not empty only when you click on it. or am i missing something?

Comment: Change first if from `if ($('#lstbx_new_repeat_requests').val().length > 0)` to `if(false)` and it should go to other `else if` :). On a serious note do `console.log($('#lstbx_new_repeat_requests').val().length)`

Comment: `the val() of the listbox is not empty only when you click on it` No. the val() is the value attribute of the selected option so unless the selected option is like `<option value="">` Its always going to result in true

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about then.. something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/HRXFx/?  it's working fine here.  If you could make a fiddle and replicate your issue it would make it a lot easier for us to troubleshoot

Comment: You tried alert test in inside of each?

Comment: Question, before I write my answer: how would you like the program to handle multiple selectlists having a value selected at the same time?

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention - you can only select item from one listbox - the other two will always be deselected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with the only way it worked for me, though it may look not so smart to you, but again - it's the only way i could make it work... and i have no idea why it didn't work with the really basic if/else if way. Any suggestions or comments will be warmly accepted. Thanks all for your efforts to assist.

The class of the three listboxes is `lstbx_repeat_requests`. When a user clicks on any of the three, I capture its id in a global var. Then I use a switch statement, as below:

1. Capture the id:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.lstbx_repeat_requests').change(function() {
       //assigns a global var
       window.my_config =
       {
           lstbx_id : this.id
       };
   });
   });
   ```
2. Switch statement:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#btn_edit_details').click(function() {

       var request_id;
       switch(window.my_config.lstbx_id){
           case "lstbx_new_repeat_requests":{
               request_id = $('#lstbx_new_repeat_requests').val();
               alert(request_id + " new");
               break;
           }
           case "lstbx_approved_repeat_requests":{
               request_id = $('#lstbx_approved_repeat_requests').val();
               alert(request_id + " approved");
               break;
           }
           case "lstbx_declined_repeat_requests":{
               request_id = $('#lstbx_declined_repeat_requests').val();
               alert(request_id + " declined");
               break;
           }
       }
       //rest of the code
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zxvvV/):

```js
$('#btn_edit_details').click(function() {
    var request_id;
    $('select').each(function (index, value) {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            request_id = $(this).val();
            alert(request_id);
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The purpose of `return` is: If the first is true does not perform the rest.

Comment: That `return` is useless there at the end of the nested function. Should be modified in another way if you want to have only a single alert alerted (via a signalization variable.)

Comment: not working either. i'm going to rebuild the whole thing since i can't spot the problem. thanks a lot for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation logic is problematic.

Consider the following case:

Initially the user selects 1 from the first select list and presses edit.

[image]

The `$('#lstbx_new_repeat_requests').val()` is 1 and you will see an alert with the value 1.

Afterward the user selects the option 2 from the second select list.

[image]

The `$('#lstbx_new_repeat_requests').val()` is still 1 so even if the user selected an option from the second select list you will see an alert with value 1. **The else if cannot be reached because the `$('#lstbx_new_repeat_requests').val()` is 1** and the code inside the **first If block** will be executed.

Below you can find an implementation which solves the above issue.

```
<input type='button' id='btn_edit_details' value='edit' />
<select class="select-list" id='lstbx_new_repeat_requests' name='lstbx_new_repeat_requests'>
    <option value=''></option>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
</select>
<select class="select-list" id='lstbx_approved_repeat_requests' name='lstbx_approved_repeat_requests'>
    <option value=''></option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>
<select class="select-list" id='lstbx_declined_repeat_requests' name='lstbx_declined_repeat_requests'>
    <option value=''></option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>​

var request_id;    
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btn_edit_details').click(function() {
        alert(request_id);
    });

    $('.select-list').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            request_id = $(this).val();
        }        
    });
});​
```